How can I capture payments below specified amount?
Not a developer but I run an ecommerce store and we are using stripe. I was wondering if there's a way to capture an amount lower than the amount specified. I know there is a "request_overcapture" but is there an undercapture? or can we change the PaymentIntent to allow us to capture a specified amount?
We sell wholesale and sometimes we have to make changes to the orders, which is why they get authorized for a higher amount. We then remove some items and then the final amount is lower.
Thanks.
Tried asking stripe and tried looking for a setting but it doesn't look like it exists.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture

Yes, you can capture less than you authenticated for the payment. To do so you use the amount_to_capture parameter, shown in the API ref that you linked to:
https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/capture#capture_payment_intent-amount_to_capture
The process for capturing less than you authorized, along with an example code snippet for Stripe's current version, is shown here:
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method#capture-funds

Thanks toby — might be a dumb question, but where/how do I edit this code?

Apologies, I overlooked the bigcommerce tag on the initial question. If you're using the Stripe integration provided by BigCommerce, you likely don't have access to edit the code that is running. Instead you'll want to reach out to the BigCommerce support team and ask them whether they provide the ability to leverage Stripe's under-capture capabilities, and if so how to use it.

This is the Capture call from BigCommerce's API:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-management/transactions/payment-actions#capture-order-payment
There's no "official" native way to capture a lesser amount with the Bigcommerce API, however I believe you can achieve this by reducing the order's total amount then calling the capture.
You could do this with the Update call below, modifying both the total_inc_tax and total_ex_tax:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-management/orders#update-an-order
Note that the call @toby shared in their response (the official Stripe one) could be used too. BigCommerce uses Standard Connect and direct charges for their Stripe integration, so you could use your account's keys to call Stripe's own capture call.
As for the question "where/how do I edit this code?", all of this is server code. These actions would be far too sensitive to call from a storefront context as customer could manipulate it, therefore the code cannot be set in a BigCommerce Script or Theme file.
That said, you should be able to handle the workaround above (changing the order amount then capturing) from your Control Panel as well.
